# Disable email confirmation new register bbPress

Tags: email, bbpress

I add an bbPress forum on my wordpress. Everything looks great, but got a problem with email confirmation.

1. My wordpress doesnt have email sending configurate.
2. I dont wan't any mail confirmation for new register.

This is what I actually use :

- bbPress v.2.5.10
- Bbpress Login Register Links On Forum Topic Pages v1.2.  For be able to register in forums.

Thanks for your help.

Have nice day.